# "Name" of the route in Symfony2 relevance

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I am wondering, what is the use of the "name" of the route in Symfony2 routes.yml file

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }
```

For example here, `pattern` and `defaults` are obviously keywords, however, what the `_welcome` stands for? Is it arbitrary or a is it kind of predefined keyword for every bundle? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `_welcome` is an arbitrary, unique id for each route you have in your project. You need it if you want to generate a url out of a template or if you want to overwrite a vendor-route...

Answer (score 2):

The route name is useful for route debugging and generating urls. You will find the route name is used extensively in Twig templates when generating links with the path() function. You can also generate urls from the route name in a controller. More information [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#generating-urls)

It is good to follow a logical convention when naming routes. Something like:
`bundle_name.controller.action` is a good place to start.